# Swift2 didRangeBeacons never called

Tags: swift, ibeacon

I'm trying to implement a dedicated class to scan for a specific iBeacon (in foreground and in background) but the function didRangeBeacons is never called.

I also set the parameter NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in my info.plist.

here is the class I developed:

```
class iBeacon: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
var beaconRegion:CLBeaconRegion!

override init(){

    super.init()
    print("init...")

    let uuidString = "B737D0E7-AF53-9B83-E5D2-922140A91234"
    let beaconIdentifier = "nbuit-06B908"
    let beaconUUID:NSUUID = NSUUID(UUIDString: uuidString)!
    beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: beaconUUID,
                                                     identifier: beaconIdentifier)

    beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = true
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    if(locationManager!.respondsToSelector("requestAlwaysAuthorization")) {
        locationManager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }

    locationManager!.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false

    locationManager!.startMonitoringForRegion(beaconRegion)
    locationManager!.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
    locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
}


func sendLocalNotificationWithMessage(message: String!) {
    let notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = message
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didStartMonitoringForRegion region: CLRegion!){
    locationManager.requestStateForRegion(region)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, forRegion region: CLRegion!) {
    if state == CLRegionState.Inside {
        locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
    }
    else {
        locationManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
    }
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager,
                     didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon],
                                     inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion)  {
    print("didRangeBeacons");
    var message:String = ""

    if(beacons.count > 0) {
        let nearestBeacon:CLBeacon = beacons[0] as! CLBeacon

        switch nearestBeacon.proximity {
        case CLProximity.Far:
            message = "You are far away from the beacon"
        case CLProximity.Near:
            message = "You are near the beacon"
        case CLProximity.Immediate:
            message = "You are in the immediate proximity of the beacon"
        case CLProximity.Unknown:
            return
        }
    } else {
        message = "No beacons are nearby"
    }

    print("%@", message)
    sendLocalNotificationWithMessage(message)
}



func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion!) {
    print("Beacon in range")
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didExitRegion region: CLRegion!) {
    print("No beacons in range")
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, monitoringDidFailForRegion region: CLRegion!, withError error: NSError!) {
    print("Failed monitoring region: \(error.description)")
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    print("Location manager failed: \(error.description)")
}
```

}

I'm not able to find the reason why my iBeacon is not detected. I also checked for the UUID and name in a BLE scanner app and it seems to be correct.

If you have any idea to help me that would be great.

EDIT:

I Finally found the reason why the LocationManager was never started, I was instantiating my class like this:

```
let qualityOfServiceClass = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
        print("Running beacon detection in the background queue")
        beaconSharedInstance
    })
```

I was expecting to get this instance running in background, but by simply calling my instance like this

```
beaconSharedInstance
```

it starts and scans for regions correctly. but as soon as my app is inactive, I have the following log:

```
Ending background task
```

and my app stops scanning. I set the following parameters

```
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
```

and also set Background Mode capability of my project.

any idea why my instance is stopped when the app is in background ?

Comment: Do you get prompted for location permission?  What log messages do you see?

Comment: Yes I am prompted for permission with the string I entered in the info. Plist

Comment: in the logs, I can only see "init..." means that my init() function is correctly called....

Comment: Finally my code is only working properly if I'm adding it in a ViewController...I don't know why it doesn't work in a dedicated class....